# Query with Category and Subcategory tables

Tags: mysql

I have a PHP MySQL query that I'm trying to do... It has a list of items with categories and sub categories. I want to sort the list alphabetically, but with categories (and their containing items) in the list. For Example...

There are three tables ...
A category table (itemcats) ...

```
> itemcat   catname 
> 1         AGeneralCategory
> 2         Food
> 3         Clothing
```

A subcategory table (itemsubcats) and a column of the parent category (itemcat) ...

```
> itemsubcat     itemcat   subcatname 
> 1              2         Fruit
> 2              2         Vegetables
> 3              2         Meat         
> 4              3         Shoewear
> 5              3         Hats
```

And then the table for the individual items (items)....

```
> itemid   itemname       itemcat   itemsubcat    
> 1        Apples         2         1
> 2        Sneakers       3         4
> 3        Onion          2         2
> 4        Banana         2         1
> 5        Steak          2         3
> 6        Sombrero       3         5
> 7        Sandals        3         4
> 8        Jeep           1         null
> 9        Baseball Cap   3         5
> 10       Mountain       1         null
> 11       Bread          2         null
> 12       Veggiemite     2         null
```

And the desired results.
Note: I can probably add the category/subcategory names using PHP, but I need the list of individual items ordered like below ...

```
> [AGeneralCategory]
>   Jeep
>   Mountain
> [Clothing]
>   [Headwear]
>     Baseball Cap
>     Sombrero
>   [Shoewear]
>     Sandals
>     Sneakers
> [Food]
>   Bread
>   [Fruit]
>     Apple
>     Banana
>   [Meat]
>     Steak
>   Veggiemite
>   [Vegetables]
>     Onion
```

So far I've tried a few JOINS ... but can't seem to get the desired results... Here is what I currently have...

```
SELECT a1.itemid iid, a1.itemname iname, a1.itemcat icat, a1.itemsubcat isub 
  FROM items a1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN itemcats b1 
    ON a1.itemcat = b1.itemcat 
  LEFT 
  JOIN itemsubcats c1 
    ON a1.itemsubcat = c1.itemsubcat 
 ORDER 
    BY a1.itemcat, a1.itemsubcat
```

---

UPDATE : Here is the final, which seems to work great....

```
SELECT a.itemid,
        a.itemname, 
        a.itemcost,
        a.itemcostcoin,
        a.itemweight,
        a.itemdesc,
        a.itemcat,
        b.catname,  
        a.itemsubcat,
        c.subcatname
    FROM (SELECT
        itemid,
        itemcat,
        itemsubcat,
        itemname, 
        itemcost,
        itemcostcoin,
        itemweight,
        itemdesc
      FROM items
      UNION SELECT itemsubcat, 
        NULL AS itemcat,
        NULL AS itemsubcat,
        subcatname,
        NULL AS itemcost,
        NULL AS itemcostcoin,
        NULL AS itemweight,
        NULL AS itemdesc        
      FROM itemsubcats) 
    AS a 
LEFT JOIN itemcats b ON a.itemcat=b.itemcat 
LEFT JOIN itemsubcats c ON a.itemsubcat=c.itemsubcat 
WHERE a.itemcat='1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct your order by clause and use names for category and sub category not their ids

```
SELECT 
  b1.catname as catname,
  c1.subcatname as subcatname ,
  a1.itemid as iid,
  a1.itemname as iname
FROM items a1 
LEFT JOIN itemcats b1 ON a1.itemcat=b1.itemcat 
LEFT JOIN itemsubcats c1 ON a1.itemsubcat=c1.itemsubcat 
ORDER BY b1.catname, c1.subcatname
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5749a7/5)

For tree view you can transform this data in your application layer (PHP)

Comment: Awesome. This helped alot. I revised it with a UNION select to help with the organization (and I'll edit above).